# Unmatched Access Query to check multiple text

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have field column of data that has multiple Vendor names that are separated by semicolon's that sell a given product that I would like to confirm they match the Vendor's name within a Vendor table.  The following Access Query does what I need if there is only a single Vendor in the Product table but falls apart when I have multiples separated by the the semicolon.  Is there a way I can modify the syntax here to check multiple Vendors when they present?  Example of this would be:  "Vendor A; Vendor B; Vendor C" all in the same record for the Vendor field in the Product table and with the Vendor table Vendor A, B and C are individual records.

```
SELECT [Product_Table].[Product Name]
FROM [Product_Table] LEFT JOIN [Vendor_Table] ON [Product_Table].[Vendor] = [Vendor_Table].[Vendor]
WHERE ((([Vendor_Table].Vendor) Is Null));
```

Comment: A quick question: Could you arrange things so that you don't have vendor names separated by semi colon? I have in mind a vendor table with only one vendor name per record, with a link to the product table. So a Product  could have meny vendors and a Vendor could sell many products. This requires a Many-To-Many setup.

Comment: Unfortunately not since this is how the data is, it's basically a spreadsheet not a database.  So I'm at the mercy of the data being in this format with the many-to-one of the Vendors separated by semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a way to do this but need to create some helper objects.

Create this query as qryNumberList_:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MSysObjects.Id
FROM            MSysObjects;
```

(This query pulls unique object Ids from MSysObject table. In a brand new db in Access 2007, this returns 34 rows.  This will be important later on.)

Create this query as qryNumberList:

```
SELECT  DCount("*","qryNumberList_","[Id] < " & [Id]) AS [Number]
FROM    qryNumberList_
WHERE   DCount("*","qryNumberList_","[Id] < " & [Id]) <= DMax("Len([Vendor])-Len(Replace([Vendor],';',''))","Product_Table", '[Vendor] Is Not Null');
```

(This query creates a sequential list of numbers starting from 0 based on the Id from the previous query.)

Create this function in a public module:

```
Public Function Split_(ByVal v As Variant, ByVal d As String, ByVal p As Integer) As Variant
    Split_ = Trim(Split(Nz(v, ""), d)(p))
End Function
```

(This is simply a wrapper function for Split, which cannot be called within queries.)

After you've set this up, copy this SQL into a new query and run it:

```
SELECT  Product_Table.[Product Name], Split_([Vendor],";",[Number]) AS SplitVendor
FROM    Product_Table, qryNumberList
WHERE   (((qryNumberList.Number)<=Len([Vendor])-Len(Replace([Vendor],";",""))));
```

What this code is doing is creating a sequential list of numbers, then CROSS JOINING it against that list.  The Split_ function pulls out the part of the string denoted by the number.  So for data in Product_Table that looks like:

```
[Product Name] [Vendor]
My Product     Vendor A;Vendor B;Vendor C
```

the resutls are:

```
[Product Name] [SplitVendor]
My Product     Vendor A
My Product     Vendor B
My Product     Vendor C
```

The real gotcha here is that you will only be able to return the part of a string that has as equal or less distinct rows in qryNumberList_.  Luckily, this should be at least 34 (see note about qryNumberList_).  I've tried to do this in a way where you don't create another persistent table, and thus the limitation.

I've tried to explain it best I can, but I'm tired at the moment.  Just try it and see if it gets you what you want.

EDIT: Oops, test data I presented had a comma delimiter for the second one.  Should have been ;.

EDIT 2: Changed qryNumberList to limit number of rows to max delimiters in Vendor column in Product_Table.

Comment: Thanks VBlades.  This does the trick but seems to have a major performance issue when working with large tables.  I tried this is with a table of over 2000 records and it's very slow to run any query involving this one.  Like literally having to wait several minutes if to sort supporting query using this one.  Any tips on making this more performant on large tables?

Comment: Hmm.  If you have a mature db that has plenty of objects, I can see MSysObjects getting bloated and producing a lot of rows in qryNumberList.  I've made an edit to qryNumberList to account for this, only bringing back the relevant number rows (this is the number which represents the max delimiters in row in Product_Table).  That should cut down on the implicit cursor in WHERE clause in the final query.  Give it a shot, but ymmv.

Comment: Thanks, that did seem to help some but still kind of slow to respond.  I'm not really working with a db here, it's just links to a couple of Excel spreadsheets that each have over 2000 rows of data.  The qryNumberList_ has 47 records and the qryNumberList has 7.  Any chance you have any other tuning tips?

Comment: Hmm.  I'll think about it, but without having your environment in front of me, I can't really think of much.  I guess you may have overhead with the linked tables as well.  Access is particularly poor about this kind of complex subquerying/subaggregation work, in my exprience.  May think about bringing the data into a temp table and just normalizing it before pulling your main query, if we can't think of anything else.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the tip.  I"m marking this as answered.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't get a more ideal answer.  If I have time, I'll play around and see if I can figure out anything else.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the `inSTR` function instead of `=`.

I.e,

```
SELECT [Product_Table].[Product Name]
FROM [Product_Table] LEFT JOIN [Vendor_Table] 
ON inSTR([Vendor_Table].[Vendor], [Product_Table].[Vendor]) > 0
WHERE ((([Vendor_Table].Vendor) Is Null));
```

I might help you or at least give a start point.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply TeeKea.  I'm not seeing where I would enter the inSTR function.  Would that be in the FROM statement after the ON?  I tried that and it seemed to have the same behavior.

Comment: I tried what you have above and it doesn't help, but on the ON statement, if I put the Product_Table.Vendor first, it is closer to working.  But its still misses partial matches.  Like if one of the multiples does not match a Vendor record it still considers a match.  It does catch if the entire column doesn't match, just not partials.  So I need to find a way to check a partial match.